# SQL Server Nested Queries on multiple tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, nested, subquery

I have a database with tables **GridData**, **FormList** and **FormData**.

I need to pull a field called **Value** from the **FormData** table, but cannot figure out how to structure the query. I can run it one-by-one and it gives me the result, but need to include it together in a table output.

The query, when I run it step-by-step is:

*Select * from **GridData** where GridName = 'uwg'* -- returns:

```
FormId      GridName        Example Field
1244135     uwg             9
1244135     uwg             10
1244135     uwg             11
1244135     uwg             7
1244135     uwg             66
```

Using that **FormID** field, I lookup the **FormList** table

*Select * from **FormList** where FormID = 1244135* -- returns:

```
JobId       FormName        FormId
1241899     ExampleForm     1244135
```

Then querying the SAME **FormList** table where FormID = JobID from above..

*Select * from **FormList** where FormID = 1241899* -- returns:

```
JobId       FormName        FormId
1241894     ExampleForm2    1241899
```

**AGAIN..** querying the SAME **FormList** table where FormID = JobID from above..

*Select * from **FormList** where FormID = 1241894* -- returns:

```
JobId       FormName        FormId
1241893     ExampleForm3    1241894
```

The JobID from this result is the ID I need to reference in the **FormData** table to return the value I need...

*Select **Value** from **FormData** where FormID = 1241893 and Name = 'ProductName'* -- returns:

```
Value
12345
```

My goal here is to be able to return all the values from the **GridData** table, with the corresponding entry in the **FormData** "Value" field.

I'm really struggling with how to write this query!

I've tried the following, but it returns multiple duplicate entries. The **Value** field contains multiple data types, and I'm only interested on the value from this table where **FormData.Name = 'ProductName'**

```html
SELECT Value,
        RecordId,
 GridData.FormId,
 GridName,
 ExampleField
      
  FROM GridData

  JOIN FormData

  ON GridData.FormId = FormData.FormID
   
  WHERE GridData.FormId IN

  (SELECT FormList.FormId FROM FormList WHERE FormList.FormId IN 
  (SELECT FormList.FormId FROM FormList WHERE FormList.FormId IN 
  (SELECT FormList.FormId FROM FormList WHERE FormList.FormId IN 
  (SELECT FormData.FormID FROM FormData))))

  AND FormData.DataItemName = 'JobProductName'
```

Comment: Based on your description the sub-SELECTs of FormList should select the `JobID`, not the `FormId`. Also, put the `AND` clause in the parentheses with the FormData-SELECT)

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a recursive query. I also don't understand why you aren't including the FormData.Name = 'ProductName' in your query unless you just aren't syncing your explanation with your description.

Comment: Is the recursion of arbitrary depth or just depth three?

Comment: @TToni oversight on my part on the OP with the JobID field.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I'm trying to filter the return on the Value to where Name is  'JobProductName' - I'm probably not doing it correctly tho. When I ran without it returned multiple (duplicate records).

Comment: @RossPresser The depth is consistent for all records I need to return as per OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Value, RecordId,GridData.FormId,GridName,ExampleField
FROM GridData
Join FormList  On GridData.FormID = FormList.FormID
Join FormList A On FormList.JobID = A.FormID
JOIN FormData On A.JobID = FormData.FormID
Where FormData.DataItemName = 'JobProductName';
```

Comment: This worked, however I get an error after about 50,000 rows with **"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.""

It's worth mentioning I'm using 3 columns as an example, there's approx 80.

Comment: Also worth noting expected row returns of 2,980,000

Comment: Are you using Subqueries in Select or where caluse of the above mentioned query ? When subquery is used in select clause it should return only 1 record. To make sure use Top 1, but this can lease to unesired results. If used in where clause, dont compare with =,< operates that expect single value. Instead use In operator.

Comment: This helped a lot but was missing a level of depth.

Answer (score 1):

The query that I managed to extract the data with was:

```
Select  FD.Value, G.*
FROM    GridData G

JOIN FormList FL1 ON FL1.FormID = G.FormID
JOIN FormList FL2 ON FL1.JobID = FL2.FormID
JOIN FormList FL3 ON FL2.JobId = FL3.FormID
JOIN FormData FD ON FL3.JobId = FD.FormID

WHERE FD.DataItemName = 'ProductNameHere' and G.GridName = 'GridNameHere'
```

The posts below helped in getting to this conclusion - thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        GD.*
              ,FD.value
    FROM      GridData GD
LEFT JOIN     FormList FL
           ON GD.FormID = FL.FormID
LEFT JOIN FormList FL1
           ON FL.JobID = FL1.FormID
LEFT JOIN FormData FD
           ON FL1,JobID = FD.FormID
    WHERE GD.GridName = 'uwg'
      AND FormData.DataItemName = 'JobProductName'
```

Comment: Thanks - but this returns only one field.

Comment: Oups, mea culpa. I corrected with the columns you wanted

Comment: I ran this and it does return the row, it also return duplicates as the filter on FormData.DataItemName = 'JobProductName' wasn't there.

As per above, if I run the query with no filters, it only returns 50,000 of expected 2.9m - but with above, I received an error, I didn't here..

Comment: I added the filter to my answer. You should try the query on a smaller part of your DB (which you'll know for a fact which rows are to be returned) and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try running the query below, level by level?

Level one is ***GridData*** alone (lines 14-16), next level is (11-17), and then repeat until the top. This way if things go wrong, you can check *when* do they do. Either that or you reach the top problem-free :)

Maybe it can be rewritten better, but let us at least get a working version for now.

```
SELECT [Value] -- 12345
FROM FormData
WHERE [Name] = 'ProductName'
  AND FormID IN (
    SELECT JobId -- 1241893
    FROM FormList
    WHERE FormID IN (
        SELECT JobId -- 1241894
        FROM FormList
        WHERE FormID IN (
            SELECT JobId -- 1241899
            FROM FormList
            WHERE FormID IN (
                SELECT FormId -- 1244135
                FROM GridData
                WHERE GridName = 'uwg'
            )
        )
    )
)
```